# DynamoDB access pattern for storing shopping history

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

What is a solid DynamoDB access pattern for storing data from a bunch of receipts of identical format? I would use SQL for maximum flexibility on more advanced analytics, but as a learning exercise want to see how far one can go with DynamoDB here. For starters I'd like to query for aggregate overall and per product spending for a given time range, track product price history, sort receipts by total, stuff along those lines. But I also want it to be as flexible as possible for future queries I haven't thought of yet. Would something like this, plus some GSI's, work?

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| pk          | sk                     | unit $ | qty | total $ | receipt total | items
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| "product a" | "2021-01-01T12:00:00Z" | 2       | 2   | 4      |               |
| "product b" | "2021-01-01T12:00:00Z" | 2       | 3   | 6      |               |
| "receipt"   | "2021-01-01T12:00:00Z" |         |     |        | 10            | array of above item data

| "product a" | "2021-01-02T12:00:00Z" | 1.75    | 3   | 5.25   |               |
| "product c" | "2021-01-02T12:00:00Z" | 2       | 2   | 4      |               |
| "receipt"   | "2021-01-02T12:00:00Z" |         |     |        | 9.25          | array of above item data
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: DynamoDb does not support aggregates, so you'll need to maintain them yourself as you insert items. The rest of the access patterns are doable, but flexibility for future access patterns is not one of DynamoDb's strengths. Instead, you build your data model based on the access patterns you know, not the access patterns you might have in the future.  There's really not a way to make your data model more flexible for future access patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You** have to decide your access patterns, and build the design of the dynamo off that not the other way around.  No one outside your team/product can tell you what your access patterns are. That entirely depends on your products need.

You have to ask: What pieces of Information do you have, and what do you need to retrieve when you have those pieces of information? You then have decide what is the most common ones that will be done the most and craft your PK/SK combinations off that. If you can't fit all your queries into just one or two bits of information, you may want to set up an Index - but Index's should be maintained only for far less often accessed queries.

If you need to, its also Accepted Practice to enter the same information twice - in two documents in the table - as writes are easier/cheaper than multiple reads (a write is pretty much one WCU per document - any query/scan can be multiple RCUs even if you only need one part -- plus Index's being replications of the table mean there is a desync chance if you write/read too quickly or try to write/read the same document in parallel calls)

Take your time now to sit down and consider everything your app will need to query the dynamo for. The more you can figure out now, the better, and if you can set your PK to something that will almost always be available to the calling function trying to query then you will be in a much better state.